How to specify the specific node connection/data flow in the tensorflow or pytorch?
The neurons in the tensorflow were often assumed to be fully connected layers, i.e.
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 1), activation='relu', input_shape=(10, 1, 1)), # layer 1
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'), # layer 2
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'), # layer 3
}

Is it possible to specify the connection between the layers? i.e. the 2nd neuron in the layer 2 is connected to only the 3rd neuron in layer 3, with directed graphs.
[(2,3),(3,3)], [(2,2),(3,1)], 

or even the non trivial back flow
[(3,3),(2,3)], [(2,3),(3,5)],  

where the connection such as
[(1,2),(2,3)], 

did not exist, i.e. the weight was always zero and can not be trained.
How to do it in tensorflow or pytorch?

Not with the Dense layer, dense layers have all connections (hence the name). I'm pretty sure there must be a way to do it though, at least the first case. I'm not sure what do you ask for from the 2nd case (backflow)

For torch, I suggest to have a look at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html and https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/masked.html. (I beleive, both tools supposed to have same semanticks, but different implementation, first one aimed on sparse graphs). Thow, both tools still considered experimental.
import torch

b = torch.randn((3,2), requires_grad=True)

a = torch.tensor([[7., 0, 0], [1, 9, 0]]).requires_grad_()
z = torch.mm(a, b)
z.sum().backward()
print( a.grad)

a_sparse = torch.tensor([[7., 0, 0], [1, 9, 0]]).to_sparse().requires_grad_()
y = torch.sparse.mm( a_sparse, b)
y.sum().backward()
print( a_sparse.grad)


tensor([[-0.4728,  2.9213, -0.2959],
    [-0.4728,  2.9213, -0.2959]])


tensor(indices=tensor([[0, 1, 1],
                   [0, 0, 1]]),
   values=tensor([-0.4728, -0.4728,  2.9213]),
   size=(2, 3), nnz=3, layout=torch.sparse_coo)
   

